# Itunes App Store Release Date Missing

Tags: itunes, windows, ios-appstore

I use the Windows OS and iTunes 11.1 and recently I noticed that the last few version of the Itune App Store they had made changes to the viewing of app in both iphone & ipad. The old version can view app according to their release date ( date shown ) but now under the release date for the app ( date shown is remove ). I had problem viewing the lastest app since last view under the respective category.

Is there a way to show the release date of the app in the current app store?

Comment: I see the release date for each app I browse from the App store on the Mac iTunes 11 - but I'm guessing you are browsing the apps that you have already downloaded onto iTunes for local syncing?

Comment: I'm not browsing the app that I have already downloaded am browsing at the games ( paid & free ) category cannot see the release date although can arrange according to it please advice

Comment: You did scroll down to the bottom of the listing and see the release date posted? It's just above the show all versions control in blue. http://cl.ly/RYbf

Comment: now trying a few app but no release date shown according to your solution please advice

Comment: Have a look at the [help] - you might add a screen shot to show us what you're seeing or list exact apps so that someone else can confirm that the release date for them is showing correctly. Until it's more clear what exactly you aren't getting, I can't really offer better help. The good thing is anyone else can offer an answer - you might have to be patient, though.

Comment: Let try this app. ( iTunes stores-app store-ipad-games-paid-action taxi app ) Can you find the release date?

Comment: Able to locate the release date for this app?

Comment: Post the share link to the app - there's no taxi I can find in the us store. Something like https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/taxi-cab/id647775488?mt=8 would let me locate the app in the first place.

Comment: sorry for the confusion the app name is call action taxi under game (racing category) please advice

Comment: Hopefully my answer to the question shows you how to look it up using the "copy link" function and a web browser. Cheers!

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/sg/app/actiontaxi/id691116276?mt=8

Comment: please advice the release date how to locate it

Comment: Sep 20, 2013 - version 1 - no other version history for that app

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand the question, I offer two answer paths:

- If you are looking for an application version update date (sometimes also called a "release date" by technical professionals) within the App Store: While viewing an individual app, have the "Details" button selected, then scroll down to the bottom where you can select what is called "Version History" to see consecutive application versions of the particular app, version number with a version update date if that information has been posted.
- Another discussion about App Store Missing Application Review Dates is taking place in [this Apple Support Communities thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23528705?tstart=0#23528705?tstart=0).

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the "Release Date" tab to see apps sorted by the release date (newest to oldest), that's no longer available on the iPhone since iOS 6. It is still available on the iPad within the category views.

Read more at [iOS 6 App Store sorting options change](http://blog.neemware.com/2012/09/24/ios6-app-store-sorting-developer/)

Comment: I had the same problem on itune app store in laptop please advice

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some smaller apps lack this data, but since I don't have access to their internal data that they used to publish the app in iTunes connect, it's hard to tell if this is a bug or delay getting the data to iTunes or the servers iTunes contacts or a design choice where the more popular apps get release dates in the iTunes view.

For example - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/taxi-cab/id647775488?mt=8

In iTunes on OS X - there is no release date listed. When you go to safari to look at that app, the release date is listed as May 17, 2013 for version 1.0 of the app.